# PermissionsPlugin - Photos vs Media Library?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, uwp, permissions

I'm a bit confused using the [PermissionPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin), in connection with the [MediaPlug](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin), for Xamarin.Forms.  I'm building functionality to allow a user to select an existing picture from their device to use in my app.  (The MediaPlugin handles that part fine).

My confusion is that the permissions enum contains both `Photos` and `MediaLibrary` values, and I'm not sure which one to use or if I need to request both.  The app is targing Android, iOS and UWP, so if it is different between platforms I'd like to know that as well.

What is the difference between those values, and which one(s) do I need for each platform?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

according to the [release notes](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin/blob/e13201327fc09723d9ea8b6b2c3f26efb1d65863/CHANGELOG.md#210) for 2.1.0

> Add MediaLibrary permission for iOS's MPMediaLibrary

which is used for the Music library, not photos

Comment: Ah, I didn't know the media library was for music.  Thanks!